# 'onunload' event to close a popup window

Tags: javascript, popupwindow, onunload

I am using the following code to generate a images on a page (from a passed array in an .ejs page) and a 'popup' window on a page when an image is 'clicked':

```js
addEventListener("load", initialize);
addEventListener("onunload", tidy);

const vitals = document.querySelector('#passed'); //reference the 'passed' information to the page

const _convert = vitals.dataset.pix.split(",");
//convert the passed ('gallery_list') string into an array...
var _limits = vitals.dataset.size;
//set limit to # of items in 'gallery_list' array...
var generator;


function tidy() {
  console.log("FIRED UNLOAD: ");
  generator.window.close(); // Closes the new window
}

function initialize() {

  var _count = 0,
    _str = vitals.dataset.username;
  var _tally = 0; //'count' the # of 'containers' and 'rows' in usage...

  if (vitals.dataset.size > 20) {
    _limits = 20;
  } //limit to 20 items per page... 

  for (_count = 0; _count < _limits; _count++) {

    //**CREATE WITHIN PROPER 'COLUMNS'...WHEN APPLICABLE...

    if ((_count === 0) || (Number.isInteger(_count / 5) == true)) {
      if (_count != 0) {
        _tally += 1
      }
    }

    //**CREATE CONTENT HERE...

    //**ADD THE PHOTO...
    _item = document.createElement("img");
    _item.setAttribute("class", "gallery_pix");
    _item.setAttribute("id", "pix_" + _str);
    _item.setAttribute("src", "/galleries/pix/" + _convert[_count]);
    _item.setAttribute("alt", "picture of " + _str);
    _item.setAttribute("width", '100%');
    document.getElementById("group_" + _tally).appendChild(_item);
    //**

    //**

  } //for loop

  //Get an array of photo images from the page
  var _photos = document.querySelectorAll(".gallery_pix");

  //Loop through the resulting array
  for (var i = 0; i < _photos.length; i++) {
    _photos[i].addEventListener("click", function() {

      var _img_select = this.src;
      var _img_id = this.id;

      var _splits = _img_id.search("_"); //return the position of the FIRST "underscore ('_')
      _pix_name = _img_id.substring(_splits + 1); //return the 'name' of the clicked image

      //**CREATE A POPUP WINDOW...WHEN AN IMAGE IS 'CLICKED'
      generator = window.open('', 'pops', 'height=400,width=500');
      generator.document.write('<html><head><title>Popup</title>');
      generator.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">');
      generator.document.write('</head><body>');
      generator.document.write("<div>");
      generator.document.write("<h1>Out with the old, in with the new!</h1>");
      generator.document.write("</div>");
      generator.document.write('</body></html>');
      generator.document.close();

      var sheet = generator.document.createElement('style')
      sheet.innerHTML = "div {border: 2px solid black; background-image: _img_select; background-color: blue;}";
      generator.document.body.appendChild(sheet);
      //**

    });

  } //for loop

}
```

The popup is created successfully however it does not close when the page is changed.  The event listener for the 'onunload' does not seem to execute...since I am not seeing my message in the console to indicate that the function had fired...

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: You added addEventListener to what, i don't see it bind to anything? Also if you generate pop on load of the page, closing the page and popup wont make any difference as on next load its gonna generate again. This is confusing... Also, create [mre]

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Please see my revised code, I believe that would suffice for a reproducible example.  I have included the 'populate' of images on the page and the associated event listener for a 'click' of each/any image.

Comment: @ikiK `addEventListener`, when called as shown, is bound to the current `window` (i.e., the global object).

Comment: The `unload` event is named just that. No "on" in its name when passed to `addEventListener`.

Comment: Thank you for that catch.  I changed my event listener to "unload" and it seems the popup closes as it should when I navigate away from the 'main' (parent) page.  Much appreciated!